# SQL filter out based on different nullable columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table where there is 3 nullable foreign keys. Lets say `T1_Id`, `T2_Id`, `T3_Id`.
Now those foreign keys are joined using `left join` and the respective tables have `Enabled` column indicating if the row is enabled obviously.

I want to filter out based on this flag, but there is 2 different scenarios.

First scenarion: `T1_Id` **will not be NULL** so then check if `T1_Id.Enabled` is 1 and then if `T2_Id` is not `NULL` also check if `Enabled` flag is 1 **and then if** `T3_Id` is not `NULL` also check the `Enabled` flag.

Second scenario is where `T1_Id` **will be null**. In that case filter out as above but without taking `T1_Id.Enabled` as consideration.

Example query:

```
SELECT [p].[Id], 
FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table1] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [p].[T1_Id]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [p].[T2_Id]
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table3] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [p].[T3_Id]
WHERE [p].[Id] = SomeId
// HOW?
ORDER BY [p].[Id]
```

I expect this can be done with `CASE` but I'm not sure how.

Example data in first scenario:

```
+-------------------------+
| Id  T1_Id  T2_Id  T3_Id |
+-------------------------+
| 1   1      1      NULL  |
| 2   2      2      3     |
| 3   3      NULL   NULL  |
| 4   1      NULL   NULL  |
| 5   3      2      1     |
| 6   NULL   1      NULL  |
| 7   NULL   2      3     |
| 8   NULL   3      NULL  |
| 9   NULL   3      1     |
| 10  NULL   2      1     |
+-------------------------+
```

Table 1:

```
+-------------+
| Id  Enabled |
+-------------+
| 1   1       |
| 2   1       |
| 3   1       |
+-------------+
```

Table 2:

```
+-------------+
| Id  Enabled |
+-------------+
| 1   0       |
| 2   1       |
| 3   1       |
+-------------+
```

Table 3:

```
+-------------+
| Id  Enabled |
+-------------+
| 1   0       |
| 2   1       |
| 3   1       |
+-------------+
```

In this scenario the query should return `Id: 2, 3, 4, 7, 8`

Comment: The question seems to be very interesting. Can you please provide us with some test data and desired result please?

Comment: may be put a sample on http://sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: @ekochergin added some sample data

Comment: how 3 and 4 can be in the output when t2_id is null for both of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT [p].[Id]
FROM [dbo].[SomeTable] AS [p]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table1] AS [t1] ON [t1].[Id] = [p].[T1_Id]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table2] AS [t2] ON [t2].[Id] = [p].[T2_Id]
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table3] AS [t3] ON [t3].[Id] = [p].[T3_Id]
WHERE (p.T1_Id IS NOT NULL AND t1.Enabled =1 OR p.T1_Id IS NULL) 
    AND (p.T2_Id IS NOT NULL AND t2.Enabled=1 OR p.T2_Id IS NULL)
    AND (p.T3_Id IS NOT NULL AND t3.Enabled=1 OR p.T3_Id IS NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it's much easier if you just flip the logic:  you want to know if the foreign keys *don't have* a matching row with `Enabled = 0`

```sql
SELECT t.Id
FROM dbo.SomeTable t
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table1 t1
    WHERE t1.Id = t.T1_Id
    AND t1.Enabled = 0
) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table2 t2
    WHERE t2.Id = t.T2_Id
    AND t2.Enabled = 0
) AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM dbo.Table3 t3
    WHERE t3.Id = t.T3_Id
    AND t3.Enabled = 0
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=001daedb892c968a65f027f180cb88fa)